# How do I locate "working compiler" on my Mac through python?

Tags: python, xcode, macos, compilation

Just learning python, but am attempting to install packages (specifically, NLTK and PyYAML). Whenever I type:

```
    sudo python setup.py install
```

The code compiles (a lot) and always ends with:

```
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler
"Cannot locate working compiler")
```

Any suggestions? My mac has version 10.6.8 if that helps...

EDIT: The solution to download XCode does not work for Macs that are not version 10.7, can someone direct me to an older version?

Comment: Install XCode; you'll find it in the App Store. Once installed, from the preferences install the command-line tools. *Then* install your packages again.

Comment: If it can't find a working compiler, I doubt "The code compiles (a lot)..."

Comment: XCode 4 for Snow Leopard is tough to find because it was never free; only paid developers see it.  Apple briefly decided to try charging for development tools, and users of OSX 10.6.8 still suffer the fallout.  XCode 3.2 is still free and can be downloaded (create a free Apple Developer account), as is XCode 4 if you buy a newer version of OSX.